# Python classes the Java way

Tags: python

I am in the need to write a Python package with a structure like this:

```
ElectricalSolver {DIR}
      bus.py
      line.py #contains the class lineInterface
      ...
      Solver1 {DIR}
         line.py #(specific implementation of lineInterface for the solver 1, contains the line class)
```

I would like to have one class per file, and I'd like to import the class directly when I call import on the file like so:

```
import ElectricalSolver.Solver1.line
```

Instead, currently I have to do:

```
from ElectricalSolver.Solver1.line import line
```

How can I indicate to load a class by its containing filename? (like in JAVA)

Is that a good python practice anyway?

Comment: Why do you want to have only one class per file?

Comment: I don't get your question; how do you want to use it in your script? Directly as `l = line()`? Then the second option is fine, right?

Comment: Start reading here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: Convention: Python uses all lowercase names for packages and modules, and CamelCase for class names. Your reversal (more or less) of this convention tripped me up upon first reading.

Comment: Why don't you write an `__init__.py` in `ElectricalSolver` that contains e.g. `from bus import bus`? Similarly in `Solver1` with `from line import line`.

Comment: Another [resource](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) on packaging. Python != Java, it supports multiple classes/functions per file, you'll just have to say which.

Comment: What @Evert is referring to is documented in PEP8: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. Adhere to that convention, it makes your code easier to understand and maintain by others.